# chroot "jail" - what is it and how do I use it?

Tags: chroot

I have heard/read a lot about the chroot jail under linux but have never yet used it (I use Fedora day-to-day), so what is a chroot "jail"? When and why might I use it/not use it and is there anything else I should know? How would I go about creating one?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

A chroot jail is a way to isolate a process and its children from the rest of the system.  It should only be used for processes that don't run as root, as root users can break out of the jail very easily.

The idea is that you create a directory tree where you copy or link in all the system files needed for a process to run.  You then use the `chroot()` system call to change the root directory to be at the base of this new tree and start the process running in that chroot'd environment.  Since it can't actually reference paths outside the modified root, it can't perform  operations (read/write etc.) maliciously on those locations.

On Linux, using a bind mounts is a great way to populate the chroot tree.  Using that, you can pull in folders like `/lib` and `/usr/lib` while not pulling in `/usr`, for example.  Just bind the directory trees you want to directories you create in the jail directory.

Comment: Your answer is great. One thing to mention though, chroot is not a secure mechanism (a process can break out of the jail if it becomes root and sometimes even if not). Real jails can be enforced with freebsd jails and the like. See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail#Similar_technologies

Comment: The Gentoo install process uses a chroot so you can setup your new OS before you have installed GRUB and the Linux kernel etc.

Comment: Take a look at [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) for a complete jailed shell using all the Linux namespaces. There are deb and rpm packages available. Generally, I'd recommend kernel 3.18 or later, though, due to a known problem with [not being able to install new software or do user management](https://firejail.wordpress.com/support/known-problems/) when `firejail` is running.

Comment: Great answer!--though some basic examples would be nice to see.

Comment: Can a user under chroot jail call binary files located under `/bin` that is installed by the root user? @Ben Combee

Comment: this answer is a little short on "how to use" can I get an example? some bash code? er somethin

Answer (score 65):

"chroot jail" is a misnomer that should really die out, but people keep using it. `chroot` is a tool that lets you simulate a directory on your filesystem as the root of the filesystem. That means you can have a folder structure like:

```
-- foo
    -- bar
    -- baz
-- bazz
```

If you `chroot foo` and do `ls /`, you'll see:

```
-- bar
-- baz
```

As far as `ls` (and any other tools you run) are concerned, those are the only directories on the filesystem. The reason "jail" is a misnomer is `chroot` is not intended to *force* a program to stay in that simulated filesystem; a program that knows it's in a chroot "jail" can fairly easily escape, so you shouldn't use `chroot` as a security measure to prevent a program from modifying files outside your simulated filesystem

Comment: It would be helpful to have an example of how to escape a `chroot` "jail". The [case I've seen](http://pentestmonkey.net/blog/chroot-breakout-perl) requires escalating to root privileges. Is it difficult to prevent a process escalating itself to root privileges?

Comment: It's still "confinement" so "jail" is a good shorthand. Would "Level 3 containment field" be better ?!

Comment: The term comes from FreeBSD jails. Jails is built on chroot. Jails was intended to solve the security problems `chroot` doesn't. For this reason people often mix up `chroot` and `jails` to mean the same thing. They don't. The term "jail" is said to be coined by Bill Cheswick when he set up a honeypot to catch a cracker: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/secpubs/berferd.pdf

Comment: So do you thing, isn't using `chroot jail` a good idea in [my case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011712/how-can-i-limit-a-directory-accessibility-to-only-itself)?

Answer (score 13):

Basically you are just changing the root directory of your environment.  So

```
/
```

becomes

```
/some-jail/ (or whatever directory you want)
```

When an application accesses / they'll get /some-jail/.  Also the application can't break out of /some-jail/ so you know it won't access anything else on your machine. Its a very simple way of saying 'hey you can only access these things that I am giving you, and you can't access anything else on the system.

Answer (score 7):

"When and why might I use it ?"

One use is in testing scripts (boot time and otherwise) that make absolute path references, or that run commands that you might want to intercept and log (and perhaps no-op them) - in an environment where you would not want those commands to actually operate on your running environment.

For example I have an embedded device running Linux, I would like to check the operation of some bash without 
a) running it on the real device (since I have better tools on my desktop and do not want to brick the device)
b) running it for real on my desktop (since I don't want my desktop system messed up)

Additionally, you can then discover which commands or other script files are used since the run will exit with an error whenever it attempts to run a command or shell script that is not present in the "chroot jail".

(Of course, to go the whole hog, you could run inside QEMU or Docker, or a VM, but that would involve creating a VM image etc. - much more work)

Answer (score 4):

chroot is easily understood as a more modern term virtual environment. The process gets a new, virtual, root directory to establish path visibility. This is mainly a convenient and simple way to control what files and libraries can be referenced by the process. It is very helpful for isolating from things that might have different versions available on the actual file system.

You can also think of it as a kind of filter on what is visible in the file system.

It is important to also consider changing the current working directory after chroot to avoid an unexpected view of the file system.

One thing that is misleading is the term jail. Historically there has been use of chroot to simulate what FreeBSD calls a jail others might call a sandbox. To do that requires also self reducing the privileges of the process. Not a great security model.

A common use case is in compiling software that needs to reference a specific toolchain or set of libraries and files and tools that are a subset of what the system actually has.