# Ubuntu 11.10 SFTP chroot jail problem

Tags: chroot, sftp

I am creating a SFTP server with Chroot Jail. The problem is user cannot log into the home directory. I need to keep `ChrootDirectory` value to one directory above the user's home directory (/home/jail/home in this case). I read that the directory needs to be owned by root. In that case user cannot do anything except logging into the server. Below is the sftp-specific part of my sshd_config file

```
Match User ftpuser
    ChrootDirectory /home/jail/home/ftpuser
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Output of `$id ftpuser` is

```
uid=1001(ftpuser) gid=1002(ftpuser) groups=1002(ftpuser),0(root)
```

I have intentionally added it to the root group so that ftpuser can at least login.

Output of `$grep ftpuser /etc/passwd` is

```
ftpuser:x:1001:1002::/home/jail/home/ftpuser:/bin/false
```

Permissions of /home/jail/home/ftpuser ared

```
rwx------+ 3 root root 4096 2011-12-12 12:49 /home/jail/home/ftpuser/
```

What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well after some Google-ing I found a solution. Though it's not a good practice but it did help me.

I changed the UID of chrooted users to 0 i.e. UID of root user, without changing the login shell. As a result chrooted user can access its home directory the way I need him to. And since the login shell is `/bin/false` he can't log into the system like other users (I actually tried doing `su - ftpuser` while I was logged into my machine as `root` and ftpuser didn't get the shell access).

Though this solution might not be good or preferable, it was the only workaround I could find.

Comment: Changing the UID to 0 defeats any security that the chroot may bring. [Chroot in itself doesn't provide security](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17299/debian-unstable-chroot-security-issues), all it does is prevent unprivileged chrooted users from directly accessing the filesystem outside the chroot.

Comment: @Gilles - I needed the user to log into /home/jail/home/username. But with chrooting I wasn't able to let it log in anywhere beyond /home/jail/home. I understand that the solution I posted is not good. But I couldn't find any other solution.