# Disable direct login for normal users but allow scp and sftp?

Tags: users, login, scp, sftp

Is it possible to disable direct login for normal users (like `oracle`) in Linux but allow `scp` and `sftp` for that use?

Answer (score 5):

Methods such as creating the file `/etc/nologin`, setting account login shells to `/bin/false` or `/sbin/nologin` effectively disable user accounts from logging into an interactive shell, but do not protect the system.

If you want to specifically restrict a user to using `scp` or `sftp` only, install a restricted shell that is designed to do exactly that. The `rssh` package  is a restricted shell designed to work with OpenSSH.

```
: rssh is a restricted shell for use with OpenSSH, allowing only scp
: and/or sftp. For example, if you have a server which you only want
: to allow users to copy files off of via scp, without providing shell
: access, you can use rssh to do that. It is a alternative to scponly.
```

You should seriously consider setting a `chroot` for the users logging in with the restricted `rssh` shell.

Read and understand the security implications of restricting users in such a way. Start with the `man` pages for  `rssh` and `rssh.conf`. You should also understand what a `chroot` [is and how it works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105/chroot-jail-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it).

Comment: This answer is obsolete. `rssh` is not maintained and it has security vulnerabilities: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2291/Rssh.html Debian and Ubuntu at least have removed it from all more recent repos.

Answer (score 2):

You can Add this to sshd_config:

```
Match User oracle
        ForceCommand set - ""$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND; [ "$1" = "scp" ] || exit 1; CMD=`IFS='\`&;<>'; set - ""$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND; echo $1`; [ "$CMD" ] || exit 1; exec $CMD
```

Here, I'm matching the user 'oracle'. Instead you can use `Match group scponly` to match users within the 'scponly' group. If anyone tries to connect in a way that doesn't run scp, then it will silently exit with return code 1.

If the account uses key-based authentication, you can prepend the key in the user's .ssh/authorized_keys file with `command="<above commands>"`.

While I've added some safety against manipulating the file to cause a rogue command to be executed (by truncating at any ``` &``;<> ``` characters), I can't be sure that this can't be worked around some way I haven't thought of.

This is all a bit long and messy to stick into an sshd_config file, and a typo could break stuff for other users. It might be better to create a script that does the checking for "scp", and then just call that script from the ForceCommand, thus making the mods in `sshd_config` much simpler. Check out https://serverfault.com/questions/749474/ssh-authorized-keys-command-option-multiple-commands for some examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible.

1. Set their login shell appropriately, e.g. by `chsh -s /bin/false ${user}`.
2. Tell `sshd` to use the internal `sftp-server`

   ```
   Match User ${user}
     ForceCommand internal-sftp
   ```

   `Match` blocks continue until the next `Match` block or the end of the file (indentation is just for humans), so it might be easiest to add this configuration at the end of the file.

(Substitute `${user}` with the desired username.)

Note that clients older than `ssh` version 9.0 can only use `sftp` with this configuration. From version 9.0 onwards `scp` works again because it has been changed to use `sftp` protocol internally.

Answer (score 0):

The login shell can be changed from `bash` to `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` do prevent a normal login. The login shell can be changed with `usermod`:

```
usermod user_name -s /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Some sftp clients aren't using proper sftp, but rather trying to log on and execute basic commands like cd, ls, ... . In that case use scp or another sftp client program.

Comment: This does not work at least in Ubuntu 20.04 default configuration, it uses the user's login shell to start the `sftp-server`.