# In what way isn't SFTP based on SSH?

Tags: ssh, sftp

I've just completed [OverTheWire Bandit wargame, level 18](http://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit19.html).

That was a surprise. Here are the instructions for this level.

> The password for the next level is stored in a file **readme** in the
>   homedirectory. Unfortunately, someone has modified **.bashrc** to log you
>   out when you log in with SSH.

I was thinking of a way to have the shell skip sourcing `.bashrc`. But before I found out a solution, I got tempted into simply starting an SFTP connection with the server. I didn't expect it to work. But it did. And I would like to know why. I thought SFTP runs over SSH.

For clarity, when I SSH into the server, I get kicked out, as expected.

Comment: SFTP does run over SSH. bash can also run over SSH. But SFTP does not run over bash. (note that I am using "run over" loosely here)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### On bash in general

Bash's design with respect to startup files is rather peculiar. Bash loads `.bashrc` in two unrelated circumstances:

- When it's an interactive shell, except when it's a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) (and except when it's invoked as `sh`). This is why [`.bash_profile` typically loads `.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/why-doesnt-my-bash-profile-work/88149#88149).
- When bash is *not* interactive nor a login shell nor invoked as `sh` but given a command to execute with `-c` and `SHLVL` is unset or less or equal to 1, and one of the following is true:

  - If standard input is a socket. In practice, this mostly happens when bash is invoked by [`rshd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell), i.e. when running `rsh remotehost.example.com somecommand`.
  - If activated at compile time (which is the case on some distributions, such as Debian and derivatives), if one of the environment variables `SSH_CLIENT` or `SSH2_CLIENT` is defined. In practice, this means that bash is invoked by `sshd`, i.e. `ssh remotehost.example.com somecommand`.
    If you don't know how bash was compiled, you can find out whether this option was set by checking whether the binary contains the string `SSH_CLIENT`:

    ```
    strings /bin/bash | grep SSH_CLIENT
    ```

### On SSH in general

When you execute a command through the SSH protocol, the command is passed over the wire as a string. The string is executed by the remote shell. When you run `ssh example.com somecommand`, if the remote user's login shell is `/bin/bash`, the SSH server runs `/bin/bash -c somecommand`. There is no way to bypass the login shell. This permits restricted login shells, for example to [allow only file copying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41046/prevent-a-unix-account-from-being-able-to-ssh/41049#41049) and not general command execution.

There is one exception: the SSH protocol allows the client to request a specific subsystem. If the client requests the `sftp` subsystem, then by default the OpenSSH server invokes the program `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` (the location may vary) via the user's login shell. But it can also be configured to run an internal SFTP server through the line

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

in the `sshd_config` file. In the case of the internal SFTP server, and only in this case, the user's login shell is bypassed.

### For this challenge

In the case of OverTheWire Bandit 18, `.bashrc` contains

```
…
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
…
echo 'Byebye !'
exit 0
```

So you can solve this level by doing anything that causes bash not to be interactive.

> As you discovered, SFTP works.
>  But `ssh bandit18@bandit.labs.overthewire.org cat readme` would also work.
>  As would `echo 'cat readme' | ssh bandit18@bandit.labs.overthewire.org`.
>  And pressing Ctrl+C at the right time during an interactive login would also work: it would interrupt bash, so the `.bashrc` would not be completely executed. Bash takes macroscopic time to start up, so while this doesn't work reliably, it can be done in practice.

Comment: I don't think SFTP runs bash *at all*, not just non-interactively.

Comment: @immibis I believe you are correct about that. I have used SFTP to exchange files on a user account which was configured with some application as the login shell rather than a "real" shell.

Comment: @immibis SFTP doesn't run bash. But unless the SFTP server is internal, `sshd` runs the user's login shell which runs `sftp-server`. Hence, if the login shell doesn't interpret the string `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` as “run the command  `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`”, you can't use SFTP.

Answer (score 5):

The `.bashrc` is only executed when you start a shell.

The SSH server can be configured not to start a shell for the SFTP protocol by providing the command  `Subsystem internal-sftp` in the server's `sshd_config` file.

Conjecture: it's likely that this is how the OverTheWire Bandit wargame is actually configured rather than an adjustment to `.bashrc` because otherwise the same restriction for `ssh` would also block the `sftp` server command.

Comment: Running SFTP *does* start a shell. The SSH daemon runs `/path/to/shell -c /path/to/sftp-server` where `/path/to/shell` is the user's login shell. If the user's login shell is bash, then `.bashrc` may be executed depending on how bash was compiled. It's always executed when bash is executed by `rshd` (yes, even for a non-interactive shell, bash startup is weird) and a compile-time option extends this to `sshd`.

Comment: I went and checked. Good guess, but in fact it isn't so subtle. The `exit` in `.bashrc` is only executed if bash is interactive.

Comment: @Gilles, with `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` and `echo No.; exit 1` in my `.bashrc` I get no `ssh` access to the server but `sftp` still works. (And then of course it's potentially possible to overwrite or remove the `.bashrc`. Permissions notwithstanding.) The `ssh` connection attempt fails whether interactive or not. On the other hand, if I have `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` then the SFTP service also fails when `.bashrc` is mangled.

Answer (score 4):

sftp uses the same credentials, but does not run an interactive shell on the remote machine.

An administrator can prevent an sftp user from running ssh, e.g., as described in [How to restrict users to SFTP only instead of SSH](https://debian-administration.org/article/94/How_to_restrict_users_to_SFTP_only_instead_of_SSH)