# Bandit0 'Broken Pipe Error' Problem

Tags: linux, ssh, pipe, nat

Tried to connect with `ssh -p 2220 bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org`

and after successfully entering the password, I'm met with this error:

`packet_write_wait: Connection to 176.9.9.172 port 2220: Broken pipe`

Now I've tried adding the setting `IPQoS throughput` to `etc/ssh/ssh_config` but still no luck.

Any ideas how to fix this issue without changing the adapter to Bridged Mode?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a problem on their end because it's working for me.

Comment: Are you on [level 19](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/313523/117549), by any chance?

Comment: Nope level 0 :( . I'm trying to start with these challenges.