# Start SSH session in some other directory than their home directory and lock them there

Tags: ssh, chroot, sftp

I've set up a SSH server which I've let some friends log into, both via SSH and FileZilla. I put a symbolic link to two hard drives in their home directories so that they could access some files. This has proved to be too difficult for some of the FileZilla (Windows) users and they keep getting lost in the filesystem.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to make SSH users start in some other directory than their home directory? Appending "cd some_dir" to their .bashrc only works for SSH, not FileZilla.
- Is it possible to lock the users within that directory and its subdirectories? Some users go up to / and can't find their way back, even though I keep explaining to them that they can just enter "/path/to/their/dir" in the target field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable direct login for normal users (like oracle) in linux but allow scp and sftp?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37964/disable-direct-login-for-normal-users-like-oracle-in-linux-but-allow-scp-and-s)

Comment: @uther I do not think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Do those users need a shell, or is sftp sufficient?

Comment: [Disable direct login for normal users (like oracle) in linux but allow scp and sftp?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37964) is not an exact duplicate, but it's the method you should use unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change the user's home to point to the destination directory. You can do that by editing `/etc/passwd` directly or `usermod --home NEW_HOME_DIR username` (this will also copy files from the previous one).

**Update:**
As for locking, there are not many choices other than a `chroot` jail. If you set the login shell to `/bin/rbash`, it will start a restricted shell. Among other things, that means `cd` will not work, nor will commands that use absolute paths. Read the `bash(1)` man page under **`RESTRICTED SHELL`** for further details.

Comment: I'm not sure that is what I want. I have two hard drives mounted on /run/media/haukur/, called a and b. now if I move their home directories there, I will have several directories under /run/media/haukur/ which might confuse the users, a ls could output something like:  
a  
arnold  
b  
bob  
john  
This doesn't really solve anything since they can still get out of their home directory all the way to / and finding the relevant directories is actually harder.

In any case, thanks for the reply.

Comment: if they don't need their own unique home dirs, they can share one.

Comment: That would be a good solution if I could prevent the creation of .bashrc, .bash_history and other files that clutter the folder. Googling now. Thanks.

Comment: Don't bother - you can simply delete them afterwards if they are made from "skeleton" files in /etc. It doesn't happen all the time.