# Give read-only access to specific folders?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, readonly

I would like to give read-only access to a user but I want him/her to see only the exact folders I give access. for example he/she shouldn't travel around all the server and browse to all users folders etc. even if he/she only goes up, up, up I want him/her to go to only these specific folders I allow. So firstly how can I let a specific user have access to a specific folder and then would putting symbolic links to his/her home folder would help? So they can go directly to necessary folders but not up or down?

Comment: possible duplicate of [chroot "jail" - what is it and how do I use it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105/chroot-jail-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: @Creek No, that's relevant background but it doesn't explain how to set this up.

Comment: @Gilles you're right, this looks more relevant [Chroot environment for SSH using Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ap-chroot-ssh-env.en.html)

Answer (score 19):

You should set necessary directory permissions.
For directories they are:

- **read**: permitted to view files and sub-directories in that directory
- **write**: permitted to create files and sub-directories in that directory
- **execute**: permitted to enter into a directory.

For files the situation is similar, it's quite obvious, so you can handle it on your own.

Numeric these permissions:

- *read* - **4**
- *write* - **2**
- *execute* - **1**

To edit permissions use `chmod`. Usage: `chmod xyz <file or directory>`

- **x** - the sum of **owner** permissions
- **y** - the sum of **owner group** permissions
- **z** - the sum of **rest users/groups** permissions

Example:

```
$ chmod -R 664 /home/jack/
```

jack and jack's group will have *read+write* access to /home/jack and **all** it's sub-directories. The rest will have only read access. `-R` option here used to *recursively* set permissions.

Other example:

```
$ chmod 700 /home/jack/video/
```

will give jack full access to `/home/jack/video`directory.  See also: `chown`, `chgrp` for changing owner and owning group.

Comment: While this is marginally relevant background, the question isn't about the details of directory permissions, it's about setting up a restricted environment.

Comment: There's no need for `chroot` here, I assume, the problem can be easily solved by setting necessary permissions.

Answer (score 3):

i also don't read necessary to set up chroots . to prevent from go up parent directories , assign a strict permission .

```
$ mkdir --parent 1/2/3
$ ls 1
2
$ chmod 100 1
$ ls 1
ls: cannot open directory 1: Permission denied
$ ls 1/2
3
```

if we want to grant a user acces to /home/1 but confine the user not to see what are other materials in /home we make /home owned by root hand have permission 111 . thus the user never know if /home/2 ever exist .