# How to restrict a user to one folder and not allow them to move out his folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, group

I have ubuntu server on digitalocean and I want to give someone a folder for their domain on my server, my problem is, I don't want that user to see my folders or files or to be able to move out their folder.

How can I restrict this user in their folder and not allow to him to move out and see other files/directories ?

Comment: You might want to use separate user accounts for that purpose.

Comment: Or maybe [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/)

Comment: chmod is not good solution because i can't use it for all the folder in my server  i used before he can move out his folder

Comment: actually i have no idea about group because i didn't use it before
can you just explain to me what the benefit of it ?

Comment: Another method - https://serverfault.com/questions/497011/sftp-user-cant-edit-or-create-files.

Comment: In addition to the methods described you can use `rssh` or `scponly` jails - http://www.herethere.net/~samson/rssh_chroot.html & http://www.herethere.net/~samson/rssh_chroot.html & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I solved my problem by this way:

#### Create a new group

```
$ sudo addgroup exchangefiles
```

#### Create the chroot directory

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/www/GroupFolder/
$ sudo chmod g+rx /var/www/GroupFolder/
```

#### Create the group-writable directory

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/www/GroupFolder/files/
$ sudo chmod g+rwx /var/www/GroupFolder/files/
```

#### Give them both to the new group

```
$ sudo chgrp -R exchangefiles /var/www/GroupFolder/
```

after that I went to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and added to the end of the file:

```
Match Group exchangefiles
  # Force the connection to use SFTP and chroot to the required directory.
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ChrootDirectory /var/www/GroupFolder/
  # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

Now I'm going to add new user with obama name to my group:

```
$ sudo adduser --ingroup exchangefiles obama
```

Now everything is done, so we need to restart the ssh service:

```
$ sudo service ssh restart
```

**notice: the user now can't do any thing out `file` directory** 
I mean all his file must be in file Folder.

Comment: I switched users as `sudo su - obama` and still it can see others' files @badr

Comment: @alper This works on sftp tool. When user connect to server via sftp tool like filezilla, he can see his directory and can't go to other directories.

Comment: This worked well for me, but I want to point out to follow the directions exactly.  The ChrootDirectory needs to be the directory ABOVE whatever subdirectory you want the user to be able to, say, upload files to.  I know this is in the answer, but it drove me crazy because I kept telling it to do /data/files/, instead of /data/ .  How this helps sometimes.

Comment: @Richard That is exactly the thing I was wondering, if the parent root directory is really necessary. At first sight it seems redundant.

Answer (score 13):

Restrictions are a sensible issue, and it must be defined consistently. What you can do is to define a *restricted shell* for the user as his **default shell**.

For example, setting `/bin/rksh` (a restricted kornshell) instead of the user's predefined shell as the default shell for that user in `/etc/profile`.

**NOTE:** if the executable with this name is not existing on your system then create a hard link `ln /bin/ksh /bin/rksh` and `ksh` will determine by its name whether it's restricted or not.

The *restricted shell* will (for example) prevent doing a `cd` command, or specifying a command with a `/` (an explicit path) in the invocation, and it disallows changing the `PATH`, `SHELL`, or `ENV` variable, and output redirections are also prohibited.

You **can** still provide **predefined** shell scripts to the user that will (under the script implementors control!) allow the user to run that specific script(s) in an unrestricted environment.

Comment: This answer is going to be *much* simpler than setting up a chroot environment so I've up-voted it.

Answer (score 6):

The command `chroot` allows you to create a restricted root for a user, this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105/chroot-jail-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it) explains the concept of `chroot` and how to use it.

Update: Searching for *chroot jail set up on digital ocean*, brings up further documentation specific to their environment.
Here's a couple which I think are related to what you might need.

[How To Configure Chroot Environments for Testing on an Ubuntu 12.04 VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-chroot-environments-for-testing-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)

[How to allow restriced SSH access to chroot jailed user](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-allow-restriced-ssh-access-to-chroot-jailed-user)

Here's [one which relates to jailkit](https://github.com/DigitalOcean-User-Projects/Articles-and-Tutorials/blob/master/users_jailkit_chroot.md), which [FloHimself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65114/flohimself) suggested.

Comment: yes they explain it but they didn't explain how to use it 
i tried with some commend but that what i get :

chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory

Comment: True, but now you have heard of chroot jail, you could do more research, I've updated answer with some links to documents on Digital Ocean, which give further explanation tailored to their environment.