# Is a Chroot Jail for SSH *and* SFTP?

Tags: ssh, chroot, sftp, jails

I'm trying to setup a chroot jail, but I'm not sure how to make this work in SSH **and** SFTP. A quick question, will something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209065) work for both SSH and SFTP or just SSH? If it doesn't work for both, how can I setup a chroot jail (or an alternative) to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SSH does a chroot, then it will be effective for all processes started by SSH.

Comment: So the answer is no?

Comment: @apxx since SFTP is handled by SSH, the answer is yes. In the post you linked, the accepted answer sets up an SFTP jail, disabling general SSH (note the `ForceCommand internal-sftp`). For general SSH access as well, you'd need something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9854/70524.