# Can't connect via ssh to server

Tags: linux, ssh

I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209065) tutorial and when I try to connect to a server I get this error:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe
```

From `sudo journalctl -u ssh.service` I get:

```
Aug 14 03:16:34 my_server sshd[2280]: Accepted publickey for myuser from my_ip port my_port ssh2: RSA *********
Aug 14 03:16:34 my_server sshd[2280]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user myuser by (uid=0)
Aug 14 03:16:35 my_server sshd[2280]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user myuser
```

I created my user outside of the `/var/www` folder and added my pc shh key to `authorized_keys` on server.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?are you trying to set up password less ssh or are you trying to set up chroot jail like in the other post ? Can you paste the commands you have issued

Comment: I setupeed chroot jail from post and now trying to connect to server with my ssh.

Comment: The linked answer has a `ForceCommand internal-sftp` in the configuration. It restricts the connection to only use SFTP. You will not be able to SSH to such an account.

Comment: @Haxiel This does imo return a message similar to "this account may only use sftp to access this server" if it's configured correctly